# bash: add element before each element of an array

Tags: bash

I have an array of strings, like:

```
ARR=(aa bb "cc dd")
```

I want to call an executable with parameter like:

```
my_executable -f aa -f bb -f "cc dd"
```

So I need to add a prefix `-f` to each element of `ARR`. I did a search and find:

```
${ARR[@]/#/-f }
```

However, this will generate something like:

```
-f aa -f bb -f cc dd
```

And if I use `my_executable ${ARR[@]/#/-f }`, it will pass 7 instead of 6 arguments to `my_executable`. If I double quote the string substitution part, it will generate 3 arguments, i.e. `"-f aa" "-f bb" "-f cc dd"`, which is not what I want either.

How can I do to make it work? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a new array with the elements inserted.  Pass the arguments to the program by saying:

```
"${NEWARR[@]}"
```

Given your example:

```
ARR=(aa bb "cc dd")
NEWARR=()
for i in "${ARR[@]}"; do
  NEWARR+=(-f)
  NEWARR+=("$i")
done
for i in "${NEWARR[@]}"; do
  echo "$i";
done
```

this would produce:

```
-f
aa
-f
bb
-f
cc dd
```

<sub>Make sure that you quote your variables.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems that `NEWARR` now has 3 elements, `"-f aa" "-f bb" "-f cc dd"`. But I want it to have 6 elements, `-f aa -f bb -f "cc dd"`. I'm sorry, the title was misleading. I have changed the title.

Comment: @devnull Now thats slick!

Comment: @jaypal Stupid things happen!

Comment: +1, I'd save a line by adding both elements at once doing `NEWARR+=('-f' "${i}")`, though.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth That's a good option.  However, an extra line wouldn't hurt for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

How about building the argument list as a string that you use to run my_executable?

```
for i in "${ARR[@]}"do
  arglist+="-f \"$i\" "
done
```

This will quote all the elements in your array ARR, without quoting the `-f` (if that matters).

`echo $arglist
-f "aa" -f "bb" -f "cc dd"`

Then you can use

> my_executable $arglist